# Threads, ActiveRecord and "PG::Error: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**TL;DR** How do you close the ActiveRecord connection to the database server *after* you've joined a thread?

I have a rake task that runs a maintenance task over and over again, but needs to enforce a time limit on the tasks (and report an error, etc.). I accomplish this by using `Thread.new` and `#join(timeout)`, then `#kill` if it takes too long. Unfortunately after a few iterations, I receive:

```
PG::Error: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
```

It appears that Rails is automatically creating a new ActiveRecord connection every time the thread starts.

The problem goes away when I run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close` within the thread, but unfortunately I can not do that because of the `#join`.

Here's the simplified code:

```
while true
  thr = Thread.new {
    do_some_database_work
  }

  unless thr.join(10)
    thr.kill
  end

  sleep 1
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking this after the join block seems to work:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.verify_active_connections!
```